# Sending out Email is not working at Google Cloud Run

Tags: django, email, google-cloud-run, google-gsuite

My application that hosted at GCP Cloudrun. The Email cannot send out from there.
It work perfectly at localhost.

My email are hosted at G-suite.

Anyone have encounter this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send email from Google Cloud. SMTP port (25) are not usable. The only way is to use third party solution, such as twillio or sendgrid.

Comment: Hey, thank for the answer. In the process of looking into 3rd party services.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Port 587 to send email. It works on Cloud Run.